# add data from firestore query to array object and map them into Picker react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

my constructor has:

```js
this.ActiveDelegation = {
  cityArr: [],
  name: '',
  expiration: '',
}
```

this is how i get the data from firestore into the object and i assume it add the name inside the `cittyArr[]` i've created

```js
getDelegationList = (querySnapshot) => {
  console.log("snapshot")
  querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
    const {name, expiration} = res.data();
    console.log('res is =>', res.data())
    this.ActiveDelegation.cityArr.push({
      key: res.id,
      res,
      name,
      expiration,
    });
    //return  <Picker.Item value={name} label={name} />
  });
  console.log('test2: ', this.ActiveDelegation.cityArr)
  //console.log('test12312: ',this.ActiveDelegation.cityArr.city)

  delegList = () => {
    return (this.ActiveDelegation.cityArr.map((c, i) => {
        return (
          <Picker.Item label = {c.name} value = {c.name} key = {i}/>
        )
      }
    ))
  }
}
```

this is inside render:

```
<Item picker>
  <Picker
    mode="dropdown"
    style={{ width: 20 }}
    placeholder="choose destination"
    placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
    placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
    // selectedValue={this.state.Destination}
    // onValueChange={this.onValueChangeG.bind(this)}
    selectedValue={this.state.selectedDest}
    onValueChange={ (value) => ( this.setState({selectedDest: value}) ) } >
    {this.delegList}
    {/*{cityItems}*/}
    <Picker.Item label="select" value="" />
  </Picker>
</Item>
```

but nothing happen inside my picker.. 
can anyone help?

Comment: Could you make a snack on the expo for this?

Comment: Not sure how to do so, also it connected to the db. I can add the whole file

Comment: add your code here https://snack.expo.io and just put your response data into a file.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution. just used the map inside the render itself under the picker scope:

```
<Item picker>
  <Picker
    mode="dropdown"
    style={{ width: 20 }}
    placeholder="choose destination"
    placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
    placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
    selectedValue={this.state.Destination}
    onValueChange={ (value) => ( this.setState({Destination: value}) ) } >
    {/* onValueChange={this.onValueChangeG.bind(this)} >*/}
    {/*<Picker.Item label="choose" value="" />*/}
    {
      this.state.destinationArr.map( (city, i) => {
        return (
          <Picker.Item label={city.name} value={city.name} key={i} />
        )
      })
    }
  </Picker>
</Item>
```

fixed*